# FATAL: The Gradle wrapper has not been found in these directories

Tags: jenkins, gradle, react-native

When I use jenkins to build react-native app, it failed with below error:

```
[Gradle] - Launching build.
FATAL: The Gradle wrapper has not been found in these directories: /Users/arespan/.jenkins/workspace/ZSKQ
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Make sure that `gradlew` is found and executable for the Jenkins user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to checkout your app into the workspace using the git or other source control plugins.

I you want to build the app directly on your filesystem project using Jenkins, you can provide the path of your project relative to the jenkins job workspace as the "Root Build script" and "Wrapper Location" options